# Google Chrome Kiosk Mode Printing Delay

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I am running google chrome (version 57) kiosk mode using the extension:

`--kiosk-printing`

since updating i have noticed a 1-2 minute delay from when then job is sent to the printer and it actually printing

Im using an ESPON TM-T88V receipt printer. when i dont print in chrome kiosk mode i dont get the delay.

i have swapped out printers and laptops but still get the delay.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? or knows why i am getting this delay?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706180

Only fix so far is downgrading to version 56

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this has been resolved on Chrome 58 (released April 25th).

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706180#c22